# SQLCMD mode: environment variable syntax?

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd, environment-variables

I assume the best way to set my SSMS (SQL Server 2005) output file path during runtime of T-SQL, is to use SQLCMD mode.

How do I use environment variables (e.g. %systemroot%) in the code? The following bombs:

`:set mypath %systemroot%
:out $(mypath)"\the_result.txt"
select * from myTab`

In other words, when using SQLCMD not from the command line, but inside my T-SQL code.
I just need to sort out the syntax.

(And also perhaps, though forum protocol is probably to ask it as separate questions:

1. Is there an environment variable for the folder of this .sql / the working folder?
2. How do I prevent the line counts to go to my output file also?
   )

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to prevent row counts just like you would everywhere else - `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.

Comment: Oops yes you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sqlcmd syntax for setting variables is :setvar.  You *can* access environment variables from sqlcmd mode (using the $(variableName) syntax) however I find these case-sensitive and it's  a bit fussy about what you can and can't do.  Try this, hopefully it makes sense:

```
:setvar mypath "$(SystemRoot)"

:out $(SystemRoot)\test.txt     -- will work

print '$(mypath)'   -- oops won't work
print '$(SystemRoot)'   -- should work

go

:out stdout
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much, I would vote you up-  but since I've only just now joined the forum, I don't have the necessary reputation to do that yet. :)